# android conversor de monedas

Tags: android, string

me han pedido crear un conversor de monedas y lo hice, pero, cuando le doy a ejecutar una conversion de 1 dolar estadounidense a euro me sale esto:

por 1 dolar estadounidense, usted recibira 1 euro

incluso si trato de convertir 2 dolares a euro me sale

por 2 dolar estadounidense, usted recibira 1 euro

creo k el problema esta en la siguiente linea de codigo

```
resultado.setText(String.format("por %5.2f %s, usted recibira %5.2f %s",vCambio,mActual,result,mCambio));
```

pero no se identificarlo, muchas gracias

el codigo es este:

```
  package com.example.beeo.cambiomoneda;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String [] datos = {"Dolar Estadounidense","Euro","Peso Dominicano","Yuan Chino","Yen Japones"};

private Spinner monedaActualSp;
private Spinner monedaCambiarSp;
private EditText valorCambio;
private TextView resultado;

final private double FDoEu =0.87;
final private double FDoPdo =50.04;
final private double FDoYu =6.94;
final private double FDoYen =112.59;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,datos);

    monedaActualSp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_mactual);
    monedaActualSp.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

public void convertir(View v){
    monedaActualSp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_mactual);
    monedaCambiarSp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_monedaCon);
    valorCambio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_valorCambiar);
    resultado =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_resultado);

    String mActual = monedaActualSp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String mCambio = monedaCambiarSp.getSelectedItem().toString();

    double vCambio = Double.parseDouble(valorCambio.getText().toString());

    double result = conversion(mActual,mCambio,vCambio);

    if (result >0){
        resultado.setText(String.format("por %5.2f %s, usted recibira %5.2f %s",vCambio,mActual,result,mCambio));
        valorCambio.setText("");
    }else {
        resultado.setText(String.format("Usted recibira"));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Las opciones elegidas no tienen un factor de conversion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private double conversion(String mActual, String mCambio, double vCambio) {
    double resultadoConversion = 0;

    switch (mActual){
        case "Dolar Estadounidense":
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
            resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoYen;
            }

            break;
        case  "Euro":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYu)/FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYen)/FDoEu;
            }
            break;
        case "Peso Dominicano":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYu)/FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYen)/FDoPdo;
            }
            break;
        case "Yuan Chino":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoEu)/FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYen)/FDoYu;
            }
            break;
        case "Yen Japones":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoYen;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoEu)/FDoYen;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoYen;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYu)/FDoYen;
            }
            break;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que en conversión siempre devuelves 1 con lo cual nunca te lo va a hacer bien el paso de una moneda a otra.

Como conversión siempre te devuelve 1, al hacer esta línea

```
double result = conversion(mActual,mCambio,vCambio);
```

result siempre te va a valer 1, con lo cual no te lo va a hacer bien.

La solución sería que conversión devuelva lo que has calculado, se haría así:

```
private double conversion(String mActual, String mCambio, double vCambio) {
    double resultadoConversion = 0;

    switch (mActual){
        case "Dolar Estadounidense":
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
            resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio * FDoYen;
            }

            break;
        case  "Euro":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYu)/FDoEu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYen)/FDoEu;
            }
            break;
        case "Peso Dominicano":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYu)/FDoPdo;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYen)/FDoPdo;
            }
            break;
        case "Yuan Chino":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoEu)/FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoYu;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yen Japones")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYen)/FDoYu;
            }
            break;
        case "Yen Japones":
            if (mCambio.equals("Dolar Estadounidense")){
                resultadoConversion = vCambio / FDoYen;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Euro")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoEu)/FDoYen;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Peso Dominicano")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoPdo)/FDoYen;
            }
            if (mCambio.equals("Yuan Chino")){
                resultadoConversion = (vCambio * FDoYu)/FDoYen;
            }
            break;
    }

    return resultadoConversion; //Devolvemos lo calculado y no 1 como antes
}
```

Ahora ya devolvemos el valor correcto y debería hacer bien las cuentas.

Comment: OMG, muchas gracias, todo esta funcionando muy bien, gracias otra vez

Comment: Nada, era un fallo pequeño. Ánimo con la programación ;)